# React Redux wait for state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch-api

I Want to extract all my server call functions (HTTP GET, POST, ...) into one helper function. The helper function will be called from different react components. It will check if the JWT Token is expired or not (client side) and if expired will ask user to relogin and get a new token before sending the request to the server.

Problem: When the helper function finds out the Token is expired it will dispatch an action to show the Login Dialog however it will continue the code calling the fetch. I need to wait for the Login Dialog to change the LoggedIn state and token before calling the server however it doesn't seem to be possible to watch for this state change. (One idea is returning a promise from Login dialog however I can't understand how to return a promise and where from!)

I appreciate that all the above can be very abstract and difficult to follow so have created a full code example showing what I need.

[Sample Code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/6yqy9n762r)

*PS : If the code sandbox fails please refresh it. They seem to be having some race issue with some of the plugins!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (!prevProps.loggedIn && this.props.loggedIn) {
    // User just logged in
  }
}
```

Comment: No! Please read the question and see the sample code. My helper function is not a component

Comment: @Asha what is your helper function? `ToggleIsLoginDialogOpen`?

Comment: you can find it under helpers/serverCall

Comment: There is only one file in your fiddle. But anyway flow is still the same. You test it in componentDidUpdate and then call your helper. Or if you are using sagas you can do it in your login saga also

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but would be great if you spend some time to read the question and see the sample. There's many more than one file you have to open the sidebar on the left to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist of thunk yet, but what i can say is that you serverCall function must return a function with a dispatch parameter ([see examples](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition) here)

You must dispatch an action in this sub function (in fact, call an action creator which will put the data in the application state.

You don't have to make an explicit promise because fetch return already a promise.

I will try something like :

```js
export const serverCall = (
  url,
  method,
  body = undefined,
  successMessage = undefined
) => {

  // your code 
  return function (dispatch) {

    return fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      ...(body && { body: JSON.stringify(body) })
    }).then(response => response.JSON())
      .then(response => 
     if (response.ok) {
        if (successMessage) {
          console.log(successMessage);
        }
        dispatch(fetchData(response))
      } else {
```

index.js

```
    <Button
      onClick={() =>
        this.props.serverCall(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
          "GET"
        )
    >
```

The state is to be removed here if you use Redux. All is taken from props via mapDispatchToProps.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onLogin: (username, password) => dispatch(login(username, password)),
  ToggleIsLoginDialogOpen: IsLoginDialogOpen =>
    dispatch(toggleIsLoginDialogOpen(IsLoginDialogOpen)),
  serverCall: (url, method) => dispatch(serverCall(url, method))
});
```